# Disable login username being saved for future logins when using ctrl+alt+del in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ctrl-alt-delete

For Windows XP I have my computer set so that you have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and then input *both* the username and password to sign in. My problem is that it logs the username and the next time I open my computer the username field is already filled in. How can I turn this of?

Comment: Are you running Windows XP *Professional*?

Comment: I think so, do I have to in order to turn it off?

Comment: Yes. Answer coming...

Comment: It is also possible to turn this "feature" off in Windows XP *Home* Edition, but seeing as it doesn't come with Group Policy editor, you have to edit the registry instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use *Group Policy* to accomplish this:

[image]

To actually get into Group Policy, run `gpedit.msc`:

[image: How to launch Group Policy Editor]

You'll need to Admin privileges to make this change.

**EDIT**

For Home edition of Windows XP, you need to edit the registry. Details on what registry key/value needs to be changed can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957392.aspx). While the document is for Windows 2000, it applies equally to Windows XP.